# Cannot Graph Two LIVE Graph in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, plot

I'm new to python and tkinter but i try to make this happen now for weeks... So I have a code which reads one of the input on my ExpanderPi(Raspberry pi IO, ADC/DAC module) and now multiplies its value by 2 than write it to the output. These values and also time are saved in two separate txt file. One to the input and one to the output. All this in a tkinter after loop. Now I1m using def animate function to draw a live matplotlib graph. My problem is I can plot just one of the txt file values. If just put some random nubers into xList1 and yList1 and i also remove pulldata1 and datalist1 it can draw it...But its not live you know. How can i plot the two of them? Thank you for the help.

```
    LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
    style.use("ggplot")

    f = Figure(figsize=(6,4), dpi=100)
    
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    
    def animate(i):
        pullData = open("Input_values.txt","r").read()
        dataList = pullData.split('\n')
        xList = []
        yList = []
        
        pullData1 = open("Output.txt","r").read() #It plot just this now.. If I remove 
        dataList1 = pullData1.split('\n')           # than the first one 
        xList1 = []                                #If i remove pulldata1 and datalist 
        yList1 = []                     # and put some  values inside xList1[] and yList1
                                        # than it can draw it 
        for eachLine in dataList:
            if len(eachLine) > 1:
                x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                xList.append(float(x))
                yList.append(float(y))
        
       
            
        a.clear()
        a.plot(xList, yList)
        a.plot(xList1, yList1)
        
        
        
        title = "Potmeter"
        a.set_title(title)
        a.set_xlabel('Time')
        a.set_ylabel('Voltage')
        
      
        a.set_ylim(0,3)      

         
        
                       
     
    app = Potmeter()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=100)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you want to display on the same `subplot(111)` ?

Comment: maybe first check what you get from files. Maybe they are empty.

Comment: you forgot  code to convert `dataList1` to `xList1`, `yList1`

Comment: Yes I want to display on the same subplot. And my files are not empty.

Comment: How can I convert dataList1 to xList1 and yList1? Should i make another for eachline…?

Comment: the same way as you convert `dataList` - `for eachLine in dataList2: ...`. Without this `for`-loop your `xList1, yList1` are always empty. Maybe use `print()` to see what you have in variable in different places.

Comment: Yes it helped thank you so much!